# Expanda a response form chain.run using openAI

Tags: openai-api, langchain

I'm querying some pdf files using langchain and llm=openai 3.5

```
docsearch = Chroma.from_documents( texts, embeddings)
docs = docsearch.similarity_search(query1)
chain.run( input_documents= docs, question=query1)
```

how can I request to continue or expand the response, for example, if it gets truncated

Comment: implementing vector db would be helpful here.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Chroma, still I didn't see how that can help me. Thanks